# How to give a windows shared path and linux shared path as source for a software and rpm respectively using any resource in puppet?

Tags: linux, share, puppet, nfs, agent

I am having an windows executable and rpm in shared path that resides in a CIFS/SMB/NFS file sharing system which has a user name and password. How to pass the source path with credentials in the manifest of puppet master and run it through agent.  I am  getting "Source doesn't exist", though I am able to access the file through windows command prompt. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to understand with the Puppet agent it runs under Local System `SYSTEM` context by default, which won't usually have access to network resources. So you will need to account for that by changing the user the service runs under to another user that has administrative access to the machine.

When it works if you run `puppet agent -t` (which runs under your user context), but not when the service runs (runs under the service account), it usually has to do with a permissions issue.

I'll provide links to the documentation once it comes back up.

HTH